# Drupal 8 run composer as root

Tags: composer-php, drupal-8

My host provider allows me to use only root user (the only one with /bin/bash) on my virtual machine that I'm using to host a drupal 8 site installed with composer.

From composer website I see they strongly advise to avoid running composer as super-user/root, they say to use *composer install --no-plugins*

I tried the command *apt-get composer install --no-plugins* but outputs the error

> E: Command line option --no-plugins is not understood in combination
>   with the other option

I'm still running composer as root, even thought there is always an alert, how can avoid that?

Answer (score -1):

If Composer is already installed, there is no need to call `apt-get`, which is the standard package installer on Debian systems. `composer install --no-plugins` does the job